# Using VBA to get data from SAS and limit the data set

Tags: excel, vba, sas, adodb

I need to import data from SAS to excel via VBA. The import needs to run eg. on workbookOpen or Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick or it can be called in any macro. This is solved in the below code:

```
Sub GetSASdata()

Dim obConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim obRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Integer

Set obConnection = New ADODB.Connection
' Do not get stuck on the choice of connection provider.
obConnection.Provider = "sas.LocalProvider"
obConnection.Properties("Data Source") = "C:\path\"
obConnection.Open

Set obRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
obRecordset.Open "MySAStable", obConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly, ADODB.adCmdTableDirect

'add header row
Cells(1, 1).Select
For i = 0 To obRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = obRecordset.Fields(i).Name
Next i

obRecordset.MoveFirst
obRecordset.Filter = "Weight > 0"
Cells(2, 1).Select
ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset obRecordset, 100

obRecordset.Close
Set obRecordset = Nothing
obConnection.Close
Set obConnection = Nothing

End Sub
```

In this example I have restricted the output to be only the first 100 rows. However, the original data set is 1.4 m rows and 150 columns, and I want to be able to restrict the data import to only take columns that I define and rows which meet certain criteria. In sql terms:

```
select col1, col2, col10, col11 from MySAStable where code = MyCode and Date > MyDate
```

But I cannot find a way to do it. The first criteria is that the code should run entirely from Excel.
I have experimented some with obRecordset.Filter but the performance is poor. It takes forever. So idealy I would like to import only the data that I need. Is there a way to do this?

The

```
obConnection.Provider = "sas.LocalProvider"
```

is arbitrary. I found an example online, tested it and it worked. If someone has an answer to my problem that involves a different connection type, i am still interested to know. Very idealy the code can also be run by users who do not have SAS installed on their computer (but have access to the folder where data is placed.)

Thank you for any help

Comment: Reading my header again i realise that perhaps it is misleading. The data itself is not restricted, I just wish to restrict/limit the total data set in the import.

Answer (score 0):

I have used two methods to read SAS data from within Excel.
The first uses SAS Add-In to MS Office. Do you have this product?
You can define the source with filters, and when the user opens the workbook, it will automatically refresh agains the datasource. You can also automate the refresh task with VBA code.
Secondly, I have done it with a Stored Process. If you have a stored process server, you can set up a web query in Excel and read the Stored Process that way, using any filter you need.